# Laravel 5 how to handle model's conflicts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I didn't saw anywhere how Laravel handles conflicts on save models.

Say I have `Product` model with `quantity` attribute. How should I protect against conflicts if for example a buyer buy a product for example:

```php
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->quantity = $product->quantity - 1;
$product->save();
```

while the seller want to update the quantity:

```php
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->quantity = $product->quantity + 100;
$product->save();
```

So what will happen if they will run that code in the same time? How Laravel will save the data correctly? Am I need to handle conflicts manually?

I didn't saw any references for that kind of thing in the documentation, so any information will be helpful.

Comment: Laravel doesn't handle this out of the box, but you can structure your code to: http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code will ever run at the EXACT same time. But I do see why you MIGHT be concerned. Two users change something at the same time, blah blah. They're both in edit mode and one save overrides the other, etc.

***However***, you can use `lockForUpdate()` in Laravel. For example, like so:

```
$product = Product::lockForUpdate()->find(1);
$product->quantity = $product->quantity + 100;
$product->save();
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#pessimistic-locking

Comment: And what will happened if there is no `lockForUpdate`.. This is the "pessimistic locking" so what about the "optimistic locking"? I mean, should I use it always for editing?

Comment: Hmm, and what about route model binding? If the route finds the model for me?

Comment: All `lockForUpdate` does is "check out" the row. Prevents others from applying edits. Really, unless your user "checks out" an item to edit and you don't want others to edit until he's finished this method would apply. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry to much about it. Not sure about route binding, but I don't think it would really matter. Route Model binding binds the `Product` object - or it's `id`. You're not pulling it for edit...it's read only. Handle lock logic in controller.